# c# How to multi-use one class in winform

Tags: c#

I created multiple rows through datagridview in parent form

I create a button in the datagridview and try to call the class for each row button

When calling class, the same class is called through the data set in the parent form, but the parameters entered into the class are different.

When I press the button,

```
if(button.text = "start")
{
    TestSocketService testSocketService= new SocketServerService();
    testSocketService.FormSendEvent += new TestSocketService.FormSendDataHandler(CallFunc);
    thread = new Thread(() => testSocketService.Start(xml, Row, Column));
    thread.Start();
}
else if(button.text = "stop")
{
    testSocketService.stop();
}
```

I wrote the code like this

But an error occurs

What's wrong with it?

I want to be able to play each role while running one class at the same time

Comment: _"What's wrong with it?"_ - don't know. What's the error?

Comment: After creating two buttons in the parent form, each button calls a class through specific set data.

Comment: For example, BUTON 1 has data called TEST. Button2 has data called TEST2.

Press the button again to trigger a close event through the close function in the class.

Comment: You're going about asking questions all wrong. Please provide a [mcve], and the full error details.

Comment: When button 1 is pressed, the CLOSE function should be called through test data, but TEST2 data is shown in the last button pressed (the situation where BUTTON1 is clicked again while pressing BUTTON1 and clicking BUTTON2)

What I want to do is, when I click on BUTTON1, I want to put the data in each correctly. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "class". Do you mean object/instance of any class? Which class are you talking about?

Is "role" just a typo or do you mean row?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `TestSocketService testSocketService= new SocketServerService();` in the scope of an `if` statement.

In the `else` statement you are trying to stop a service instance that doesn't exist (or if it exists its a different one).

```
testSocketService.stop();
```

Try declaring `TestSocketService testSocketService` instance outside your `if` statement and see if it works.